# Typescript Get certain values from an array of classes

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an array of objects that look like this

```
[
 {
  applicationNumber:'227114'
  applicationStatus:0,
  dateCreated: "01-10-2010"
 },
{
   companyInformationModel:
 {
  companyInformationId: '78fe1852-5a26-4624-925c-74653de9dad9',
  companyName: 'Company Test',
  contactName: 'Test Contact',
  primaryPhone: '123-234-2343',
  secondaryPhone: null
 },
 {
   locationInformationModels:
   [
     {
       "Address": "123 Main St",
       "City": "My City"
     },
     {
       "Address": "123 Not Main St",
       "City": "Your City"
     }
   ]
]
```

I want to grab only these fields and assign them to its own array
**(application nummber, applicationstatus, companyname, contactname, Address, City)**

What is the most efficient way that can I do that in typescript? I want to assign this data to an ag-grid datasource.

```
onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.assessmentService.getAssessment().subscribe(data =>{
      let assessment =   <-------------------------Here is where I would parse the data
      this.assessmentData = assessment;
      const sortModel = [{colId: 'dateCreated', sort: 'desc'}];
      this.sortGrid(params, 'dateCreated', 'desc')
      this.gridApi.setRowData(this.assessmentData.slice(0, 10)); 
      params.api!.setRowData(this.assessmentData.slice(0, 10))
      this.loading = false; 
      console.log(this.assessmentData);
    });  
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  const data = [
    {
      applicationNumber: '227114',
      applicationStatus: 0,
      dateCreated: "01-10-2010"
    },
    {
      companyInformationModel:
      {
        companyInformationId: '78fe1852-5a26-4624-925c-74653de9dad9',
        companyName: 'Company Test',
        contactName: 'Test Contact',
        primaryPhone: '123-234-2343',
        secondaryPhone: null
      },
      locationInformationModels:
      [
        {
          "Address": "123 Main St",
          "City": "My City"
        },
        {
          "Address": "123 Not Main St",
          "City": "Your City"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];


onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
      this.assessmentService.getAssessment().subscribe(data => {
        const assessment = data.map(item => ({
          applicationNumber: item.applicationNumber,
          applicationStatus: item.applicationStatus,
          companyName: item.companyInformationModel?.companyName,
          contactName: item.companyInformationModel?.contactName,
          Address: item.locationInformationModels?.[0]?.Address,
          City: item.locationInformationModels?.[0]?.City,
        }));
    
        this.assessmentData = assessment;
        const sortModel = [{ colId: 'dateCreated', sort: 'desc' }];
        this.sortGrid(params, 'dateCreated', 'desc');
        this.gridApi.setRowData(this.assessmentData.slice(0, 10));
        params.api!.setRowData(this.assessmentData.slice(0, 10));
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(this.assessmentData);
      });
    }
```